# A general generalized homology theory

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homological-algebra

From a course in commutative algebra I know the algebraic way to define a homology theory by taking pointwise quotients of chain complexes (which can for example be obtained by taking projective resolutions of some sort).

In a course on algebraic topology, which I am currently attending, we introduced *generalized relative extraordinary homology theories* as sequence of functors $H_n:\operatorname{hTop}^\hookrightarrow \rightarrow \operatorname{Mod}_R^{\mathbb{Z}gr}$ together with natural transformations $\partial_n:H_n \implies H_{n-1}\circ R$ satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (here $\operatorname{hTop}^\hookrightarrow$ denotes the category of pairs of subspaces $X \supseteq A$ and morphisms $f:(X,A) \rightarrow (Y,B)$ which satisfy $f(A) \subseteq B$; $R$ is the functor given by $(X,A) \mapsto (X,\emptyset)$). The corresponding *reduced homology theory* is then given by $\tilde{H}(X) = \ker (H(X,\emptyset) \rightarrow H(*,\emptyset))$.

My question now is:

> Is there a unified treatment of both the algebraic and the topological
>   notions of homology theory (relative or reduced)?

Initially I thought generalized homology theories could be obtained from homologies of certain chain complexes, as for example the simplicial homology is. However a result from Bauer seems to show that this is not true in general and those theories, who come from chain complexes, are closely related to ordinary homology theories. Extraordinary homology theories seem to be very important however (Wikipedia mentions important sounding words like *topological K-theory* and *cobordism*), so it seems to me that this is the wrong approach to making the notions agree...

Yet, the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms don't seem to rely on having topological spaces as underlying category. I wonder, wether the algebraic homology functors can be expressed in a similar set of axioms, leaving chain complexes and derived functors just as a tool to obtain homology theories...

Thank you very much for your time and patience!

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a long comment addressing both (topological) homology theories coming from chain complexes and homology theories for chain complexes:

Let's suppose that your homology theory is defined for CW pairs. One way to attempt to find a chain complex whose homology is the homology of your space is to take the cellular filtration of your CW complex, and two each pair $(X_n,X_{n-1})$ we may form the long exact sequence for the homology theory which we can piece together to form a spectral sequence called the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence. This sequence starts with the relative homology of your complex with coefficients in the extraordinary homology of a point and converges to the extraordinary homology of your complex. The obstruction to this spectral sequence simply being a chain complex is if the extraordinary homology of a point has multiple dimensions nontrivial.

That is not to say that the homology theory can't arise from a chain complex if the homology of a point is nontrivial in more than one dimension. For example, unoriented bordism is maps from smooth, compact n-manifolds into your space modulo the relation of bordism which says two maps are equivalent if there is a larger map on a manifold which restricts to the disjoint union of the maps on the boundary. This can be written in terms of a chain complex (of monoids) because the boundary of a manifold has no boundary. Very surprisingly, it turns out that this homology theory is actually a direct sum of shifted $\mathbb{Z}/2$-homology, but for other bordism theories this is not the case.

I'm sure much is known about what types of homology theories factor through chain complexes, I would not be surprised, for example, if any theory which outputted rational vector spaces factored through a map to rational chain complexes.

For your question about homology theories on chain complexes, I believe these all come from tensoring with a chain complex and then taking its homology. This should follow from the fact that the stabilization of the category of chain complexes is itself. Here this just means that shift up and shift down are already inverses, and these play the role of suspension and inverse suspension in stable homotopy theory. For more information, look up hypercohomology.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment! I do know that a german of the name Bauer did some research on generalized homology theories coming from chain complexes, however I could not read any of his papers yet. As you said there are bordism theories, which do not originate from a chain complex though. Hence I am searching for a general reformulation of a homology theory as a functor from a suitably nice category into Zgraded modules, which satisfies some general form of Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. In fact I keep wondering, why I cannot find any source going in this direction...

Comment: The only things in the definition that need some jiggling are the notion of homotopy invariance and excision. These can both be solved in the context of model categories. The homotopy axiom simply will day the functor factors through the homotopy category or the model category. The excision axiom can be be replaced by a statement involving cofibrations.

Comment: In a suitably nice context you will have theorems like Brown representability and Puppe sequences (meaning you also have notions of loops and suspension). This should allow you to say that cohomology theories are in correspondence to spectra whose objects are the objects of your category. Notably, in the case of chain complexes, I believe their category of spectra is equivalent to themselves.

Comment: Though I might be sweeping a lot under the rug about stabilizing a model category, I haven’t studied it.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. Do you know of any introductory material for these things? And did I understand right, that the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms can be expressed for a functor $\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \operatorname{Mod}_R^{\mathbb{Z}gr}$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a model category? So the algebraic notions is encapsulated in the fact that chain complexes give a model category and the topological notion is encapsulated by $\operatorname{Top}$ being a model category?

Comment: It seems to me that the keyword "model category" was precisely the keyword my questions to mr. google were lacking. Interestingly ncatlab does not introduce Eilenberg Steenrod axioms on model categories directly but rather unprominently mentions a reformulation in terms of $(\infty,1)$-categories...

Comment: I think in the past a lot of people thought you essentially had to choose a side between model categories and infinity categories, but I think now people view them each of them as essential tools. To read about model categories you should look at Dwyer and Spalinski's "Homotopy Theories and Model Categories".